# The route adminregister could not be found

Tags: performance, symfony, router

We are having this error (using bitnami and php 8)

{"exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php", "line": 44, "message": "The route adminregister could not be found.", "trace": [{"class": "Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php", "function": "handleMatchedRoute", "line": 162, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", "function": "match", "line": 754, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", "function": "findRoute", "line": 741, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php", "function": "dispatchToRoute", "line": 730, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", "function": "dispatch", "line": 200, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}", "line": 141, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 21, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php", "function": "handle", "line": 31, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 21, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php", "function": "handle", "line": 40, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 27, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 86, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 49, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 39, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "handle", "line": 180, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php", "function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}", "line": 116, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", "function": "then", "line": 175, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php", "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter", "line": 144, "type": "->"}, {"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel", "file": "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/public/index.php", "function": "handle", "line": 52, "type": "->"}]}

tried already to clear cache and otimize but still the same error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the given route defined anywhere? Also, how is this problem related to [tag:performance]?